# Using TKINTER Python3: How to display input info into ANOTHER text/display box in the same gui?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to display inputted text in a gui into another box area in the same gui.
I will show a pic to hopefully make sense of my question.

I am trying to post the entire code piece but this site has too many rules.

Here is an image with what I am trying to do.
[***SEE MY EXAMPLE IMAGE HERE***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZIB4.png)
Here is my dev code:

```
        from Tkinter import *
    import io
    import math

    DB_OS_TYPE = """DB_OS_TYPE
    1 Help stuff here 

    """

    VERSION = """VERSION
    2 Help stuff here

    """

    STAGE_DEPLOY = """STAGE_DEPLOY
    3. Help stuff here

    """

    USECASE = """USECASE
    4 Help stuff here

    """

    R_nonR = """R_nonR
    5 Help stuff here

    """

    S_or_T = """S_or_T
    6 Help stuff here

    """

    INT_CLASS = """INT_CLASS
    7 Help stuff here

    """

    C_NAME = """C_NAME
    8 Help stuff here

    """

    P_NAME = """P_NAME
    9 Help stuff here

    """

    INSTALL_LOC = """INSTALL_LOC
    10 Help stuff here

    """

    O_HOME = """O_HOME
    11 Help stuff here

    """
    PRIMARY_E = """PRIMARY_E
    12 Help Stuff Here

    """

    PMP = """PMP
    13 Help stuff here

    """

    REPL = """REPL
    14 Help stuff here

    """

    PORT = """PORT
    15 Help stuff here

    """

    PORT_LIST = """PORT_LIST
    16 Help stuff here

    """

    def clickAbout1():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label1 = Label(toplevel, text=DB_OS_TYPE, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label1.pack()

    def clickAbout2():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label2 = Label(toplevel, text=VERSION, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label2.pack()

    def clickAbout3():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label3= Label(toplevel, text=STAGE_DEPLOY, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label3.pack()

    def clickAbout4():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label4= Label(toplevel, text=USECASE, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label4.pack()

    def clickAbout5():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label5= Label(toplevel, text=R_nonR, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label5.pack()

    def clickAbout6():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label6= Label(toplevel, text=S_or_T, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label6.pack()

    def clickAbout7():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label7= Label(toplevel, text=INT_CLASS, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label7.pack()

    def clickAbout8():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label8= Label(toplevel, text=C_NAME, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label8.pack()

    def clickAbout9():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label9= Label(toplevel, text=P_NAME, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label9.pack()

    def clickAbout10():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label10= Label(toplevel, text=INSTALL_LOC, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label10.pack()

    def clickAbout11():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label11= Label(toplevel, text=O_HOME, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label11.pack()

    def clickAbout12():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label12= Label(toplevel, text=PRIMARY_E, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label12.pack()    

    def clickAbout13():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label13= Label(toplevel, text=PMP, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label13.pack()

    def clickAbout14():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label14= Label(toplevel, text=REPL, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label14.pack()

    def clickAbout15():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label15= Label(toplevel, text=PORT, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label15.pack()

    def clickAbout16():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        help_label16= Label(toplevel, text=PORT_LIST, height=0, width=90, justify=LEFT, anchor='w')
        help_label16.pack()

    def loadme(self):
        path = 'my-summary'
        path_file1 = open(path, 'r')
        path_file2 = path_file1.read()

    class ComputeAaa:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.aaa_frame1 = Frame(master)
            self.aaa_frame1.pack()

            self.aaa_status_label1 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="1. DB/OS type:")
            self.aaa_status_label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option1 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option1.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option1a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option1, "1 example", "2 example", "3 example", "4 example", "5 example", "6 example", "None")
            self.aaa_status_option1a.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
            button1 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="1. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout1)
            button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

            self.aaa_status_label2 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="2. Your version:")
            self.aaa_status_label2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option2 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option2.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option2a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option2, "1 example", "2 example", "3 example", "4 example", "None")
            self.aaa_status_option2a.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
            button2 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="2. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout2)
            button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

            self.aaa_status_label3 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="3. Stage or Deploy:")
            self.aaa_status_label3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option3 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option3.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option3a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option3, "1 example", "2 example")
            self.aaa_status_option3a.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
            button3 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="3. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout3)
            button3.grid(row=3, column=1)

            self.aaa_status_label4 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="4. UseCase:")
            self.aaa_status_label4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option4 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option4.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option4a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option4, "1 example", "2 example")
            self.aaa_status_option4a.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
            button4 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="4. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout4)
            button4.grid(row=4, column=1)

            self.aaa_status_label5 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="5. R or NON-R:")
            self.aaa_status_label5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option5 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option5.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option5a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option5, "1 example", "2 example")
            self.aaa_status_option5a.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
            button5 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="5. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout5)
            button5.grid(row=5, column=1)

            self.aaa_status_label6 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="6. S or T:")
            self.aaa_status_label6.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option6 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option6.set("example 1")
            self.aaa_status_option6a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option6, "1 example", "2 example")
            self.aaa_status_option6a.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
            button6 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="6. ?", width=2, command=clickAbout6)
            button6.grid(row=6, column=1)   

            self.aaa_status_label7 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="7. Install Type:")
            self.aaa_status_label7.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_status_option7 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_status_option7.set("1 example")
            self.aaa_status_option7a = OptionMenu(self.aaa_frame1, self.aaa_status_option7, "1 example", "2 example")
            self.aaa_status_option7a.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
            button7 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="7. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout7)
            button7.grid(row=7, column=1)

            self.aaa_label8 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="8. C Name:")
            self.aaa_label8.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input8 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input8 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input8, width=60)
            self.aaa_input8.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
            button8 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="8. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout8)
            button8.grid(row=10, column=2)

            self.aaa_label9 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="9. P Name:")
            self.aaa_label9.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input9 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input9 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input9, width=60)
            self.aaa_input9.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)
            button9 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="9. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout9)
            button9.grid(row=11, column=2)        

            self.aaa_label10 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="10. Install location:")
            self.aaa_label10.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input10 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input10 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input10, width=60)
            self.aaa_input10.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)
            button10 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="10. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout10)
            button10.grid(row=12, column=2)

            self.aaa_label11 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="11. Path1:")
            self.aaa_label11.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input11 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input11 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input11, width=60)
            self.aaa_input11.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=W)
            button11 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="11. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout11)
            button11.grid(row=13, column=2)

            self.aaa_label12 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="12. Pri Name:")
            self.aaa_label12.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input12 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input12 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input12, width=60)
            self.aaa_input12.grid(row=14, column=1, sticky=W)
            button12 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="12. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout12)
            button12.grid(row=14, column=2)

            self.aaa_label13 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="13. P Name:")
            self.aaa_label13.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input13 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input13 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input13, width=60)
            self.aaa_input13.grid(row=15, column=1, sticky=W)
            button13 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="13. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout13)
            button13.grid(row=15, column=2)

            self.aaa_label14 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="14. Repl Name:")
            self.aaa_label14.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input14 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input14 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input14, width=60)
            self.aaa_input14.grid(row=16, column=1, sticky=W)
            button14 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="14. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout14)
            button14.grid(row=16, column=2)

            self.aaa_label15 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="15. Port Number:")
            self.aaa_label15.grid(row=17, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input15 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input15 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input15, width=60)
            self.aaa_input15.grid(row=17, column=1, sticky=W)
            button15 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="15. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout15)
            button15.grid(row=17, column=2)

            self.aaa_label16 = Label(self.aaa_frame1, text="16. Port List:")
            self.aaa_label16.grid(row=18, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.aaa_input16 = StringVar(self.aaa_frame1)
            self.aaa_input16 = Entry(self.aaa_frame1, textvariable=self.aaa_input16, width=60)
            self.aaa_input16.grid(row=18, column=1, sticky=W)
            button16 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="16. ?", width=3, command=clickAbout16)
            button16.grid(row=18, column=2)

            ###------------------
            self.aaa_button2 = Button(self.aaa_frame1, text="Generate Summary", command=self.save_ts)
            self.aaa_button2.grid(row=20, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


            ###I am not too sure how to read the data to display in box
            summary_box1=Listbox(self.aaa_frame1, height=12,width=50, bg='gray')
            summary_box1.grid(row=21,column=0,rowspan=12,columnspan=2, sticky=W)
            #MY TESTS
            #path = 'my-summary'
            #path_file1 = open(path, 'r')
            #path_file2 = path_file1.read()
            #print(path_file2)
            #path_file1.close()

        def save_ts(self):
            aaaSummary1 = self.aaa_status_option1.get()
            aaaSummary2 = self.aaa_status_option2.get()
            aaaSummary3 = self.aaa_status_option3.get()
            aaaSummary4 = self.aaa_status_option4.get()
            aaaSummary5 = self.aaa_status_option5.get()
            aaaSummary6 = self.aaa_status_option6.get()
            aaaSummary7 = self.aaa_status_option7.get()
            aaaSummary8 = self.aaa_input8.get()
            aaaSummary9 = self.aaa_input9.get()
            aaaSummary10 = self.aaa_input10.get()
            aaaSummary11 = self.aaa_input11.get()
            aaaSummary12 = self.aaa_input12.get()
            aaaSummary13 = self.aaa_input13.get()
            aaaSummary14 = self.aaa_input14.get()
            aaaSummary15 = self.aaa_input15.get()
            aaaSummary16 = self.aaa_input16.get()
            with open("my-summary", "w") as file:
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary1))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary2))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary3))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary4))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary5))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary6))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary7))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary8))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary9))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary10))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary11))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary12))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary13))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary14))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary15))
                file.write("{}\n".format(aaaSummary16))

    frame = Tk()
    a_compute_class = ComputeAaa(frame)
    frame.title("My Build-Out")
    ######  END OF CODE  #####################

        frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include any code. Please post a [mcve], and make sure you focus on the "M". We don't need to see code for seven different dropdowns and nine entry widgets and seventeen buttons when one or two of each will do just as well.

Comment: It does have code. you are too fast.  had to upload the stuff.  getting used to this website..

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please reduce it down to the minimum necessary to illustrate the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks all for replies.  I appreciate the patience.Please look at the image if there is too much code...  I tried some of the suggestions but no luck.....    I know there are many ways to code one task, but that is not my concern now.  I am just trying to find out how to OUTPUT inputted text into ANOTHER text box area in the same gui.    To set a premise, my first python code.   I truly think if you look at the image my question will make sense...  Well, hopefully.. Again many thanks.

Comment: The best thing you can do is start over. Create a brand new program that tries to do what you are asking, and _only_ that. Figure out how to do it in a small program before trying to do it in a big program.

Comment: Hi Bryan, that's how I got this far, doing exactly that, I totally agree with you....  Anybody have any other ideas besides Bryan's start all over. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Way too much code for me to sort through, so here is a generic program that shows how to use a textvariable to display what is entered into the Entry  in the label as the Entry is changed.

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

tk_name=tkinter.StringVar()
tk_name.set("nothing")

tkinter.Label(top, textvariable=tk_name).grid(row=0, column=1)

entry_1 = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=tk_name)
entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
entry_1.focus_set()

top.mainloop()
```